# solving exponential equation $e^{x/n}=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, lambert-w

How can I solve this equation $e^{x/n}=x$ for $x$? I have no idea how to solve it.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Lambert W function, in the Wikipedia page there is a lot of methods for solving all sort of equations related to the function

Comment: @Ken You need much more context. What steps have you tried? Have you researched the Lambert-W function like others have suggested? Also, 'solve' can have many meanings in mathematics. What exactly do you mean by 'solve'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Read this Wikipedia article, then read my solution:
$$e^{x/n}=x$$
$$1=xe^{-x/n}$$
$$-\frac{1}{n}=-\frac{xe^{-x/n}}{n}$$
$$W\bigg(-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)=-\frac{x}{n}$$
$$x=-nW\bigg(-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$

Comment: Worth noting that, when $W\left(-\frac 1n\right)$ has a value, it actually has two values, for $n>0$. That's because $W$ has two branches with different values in the range $(-1/e,0)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, good observation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to settle for approximations? If so, then we could implement simple fixed-point iteration methods.

---

$$x_{k+1}=\exp(x_k/n)$$

where $x_0=1$. This will converge to the smallest solution to your equation as $k\to\infty$.

---

$$x_{k+1}=n\ln(x_k)$$

where $x_0=1$. This will converge to the largest solution to your equation as $k\to\infty$.

---

A fairly simple brute force approach, though the convergence is fairly slow. Faster approximations may be made using approaches found in the Wikipedia linked by Nilknarf's answer.